# Copy rows from table into email if the rows meet condition

Tags: excel, vba, email, conditional-statements

I have a spreadsheet which tracks expiration dates for different licenses. It has one table in sheet1 and four tables in sheet2.

I send an email automatically when the workbook is opened. With my computer's shell:startup it opens when I turn on my computer in the morning. The code attaches the Excel spreadsheet to the email.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim emailApplication As Object
    Dim emailItem As Object

    Set emailApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set emailItem = emailApplication.CreateItem(0)

    emailItem.to = "fake.email@emailaddress.com"
    emailItem.Subject = "Please Review; Upcoming Expiration Dates"
    emailItem.Body = "Please review the attached spreadsheet as it may have dates that are expired/soon to be expired. Please note there are multiple sheets."

    emailItem.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    emailItem.Display

    MsgBox "Your email has been sent.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

I would like instead to copy rows that either state "Expires w/in 30 days" or "EXPIRED" and paste that into the body of the email in table format.
For example, when Column G2 states "EXPIRED' or "Expires w/in 30 days', return the entirety of B2:G2.

I can't share the table contents, so I made my own.
[image]

[image]

What I've tried: I've copied and edited multiple different lines of code from Ron de Bruin and other forums to paste the entire table as an image (but I can't get multiple tables from multiple sheets, can only get one table).
I've run code which returns either TRUE or FALSE and even 1 or -1, and code which gives me the contents of the table in paragraph form.

I know there are work-arounds, for example; pasting conditional rows from multiple sheets to a dummy sheet that's killed off at the end of the code. I could paste that into the body.
Or, perhaps generating multiple table pictures from each sheet. I could send one email for each sheet.

Comment: I find **autofilter** and `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` method is stable and efficient.